# How to figure out forward coordinate in xyz plane of player?

Tags: c++, c, geometry

I am currently making a mod for a game and I am able to get the XYZ coordinates of the player as well as the direction they're facing (a value between 0 and 360 degrees). I need to use this information to figure out what coordinates would be in front of the character according to which way they are facing.

For example: if x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 and the character were facing 0 degrees, South. And assuming the z-axis runs North to South, then if the character walked forward one unit, their new coordinate would be x = 0, y = 0, z = -1.

Comment: it is vector math. you normalize the direction, then multiply by distance

Comment: Are coordinates integer types? Floating point types? With respect to which axis is the angle measured? And in which plane?

Comment: Are directions measured clockwise or counterclockwise? That is, is 90 degrees East or West?

Comment: @DavidBowling (also Beta) The coordinates are floats, the angle is measured relative to the East/Clockwise.

Comment: If degree 0 is towards South, and it runs clockwise, then 90 degrees would be towards West. Right?

Comment: In 3D one angle is insufficient to define direction. Use 3d vector (dx,dy,dz) or two polar angles. Perhaps your objects are on the Earth surface (why XYZ in such case?) - so specify this explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that North is +Z and East is +X. Also, direction 0 is South and 90 is West.

```
vec3 DegreeToDirection (float degs) {
    float rads = 3.1415926535f / 180 * degs;
    float s = sinf(rads), c = cosf(rads);
    vec3 ret = {-s, 0, -c};
    return ret;
}
```

Now just add this to your current position.

**EDIT**: Here's the modified code from the comment that actually worked for the OP: (Note the lack of negation on the X return value, which probably means my assumption about the X axis was wrong.)

```
void DegreeToDirection (float degs, float out [3]) {
    float rads = 3.1415926535f / 180 * degs;
    out[0] = sinf(rads);
    out[1] = 0.0f;
    out[2] = -cosf(rads);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I didn't feel like fooling with GLSL so I just made it return `void` and had a 3 wide float array to store the new vector. And had to take away negation of `s` in `ret`. `void DegreeToDirection (float degs, float out[3]) {
    float rads = 3.1415926535f / 180 * degs;
    float s = sinf(rads), c = cosf(rads);
    float ret[3] = {s, 0, -c};
    memcpy(out, ret, sizeof(ret));
}`

Answer (score 0):

so say your character has coordinates `(A, B, C)`, you want to create a direction vector equal to one unit (lets call it `R`). I am assuming the player only travels in the x, y plane for this example so you would create a direction vector:

V = (R * cos(angle), R * sin(angle))

and you would add this vector to your players coordinates, so for a vector (x, y) the new player coordinates would be (A + x, B + y, C)